# How to run a batch on emacs startup and shutdown?

Tags: windows, batch-file, emacs, emacs24

I want to automatically update svn and commit to svn on emacs startup and shutdown. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't have a commit to svn function, since I don't use that.  However, you would probably want to use these hooks:  `emacs-startup-hook` and `kill-emacs-hook`.  See  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html  It works like this:  `(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (message "Hello World!  This is my startup hook.") ))`  If I'm not mistaken, the word `batch` implies that Emacs starts, runs a batch function, and then exits.

Comment: @lawlist: actually I mean to run a batch file on windows. Anyway thanks for your answer, it's good to start with hooks.

Comment: If what you want to do when Emacs starts up and shuts down is something that does not need to be done inside Emacs, why do it inside Emacs? Write a script that does an SVN get, then runs Emacs, then does an SVN commit. (I assume you want an interactive Emacs session.) Yes, you can do it inside Emacs too, but why, in this case?